# Evaluation of a nested sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given

$\sum_{i=1}^5 \sum_{j=i}^{12} {(2j-7)}$

My questions are :

(1)when $(j=i)$ what that actually means ?

(2) I tackled the inner sum

$\sum_{j=i}^{12}{(2j-7)}$ = 2$\sum_{j=i}^{12} {(j)}$ - $\sum_{j=i}^{12} {(7)} $

I know how to evaluate $\sum_{j=i}^{12} {(7)} $=$-7(13-i)$

I tried to use same logic with 2$\sum_{j=i}^{12}{(j)}$ it didn’t work and the solution of the textbook says that the sum of this, is **the sum of the first 12 integers minus the sum of the first i-1 integers**.

I have no idea what that means and how so.
Any clarifications please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^5 \sum_{j=i}^{12} {(2j-7)} = \sum_{j=1}^{12} {(2j-7)}+\sum_{j=2}^{12} {(2j-7)}+\sum_{j=3}^{12} {(2j-7)}+\sum_{j=4}^{12} {(2j-7)}+\sum_{j=5}^{12} {(2j-7)}$

Comment: You are swinging for the fences instead of getting down in the mud.  Change the summation to $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=i}^{7} {(2j-7)}$ and then manually write down each term, like a rat going through the maze.  Then contrast your result with the information in your query.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{5} \sum_{j=i}^{12}(2j-7)=\sum_{i=1}^{5} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{12}(2j-7)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(2j-7)\right].$$
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{5}\left[ (12.13-7.12)-(i(i-1)-7(i-1)\right]=72.5-\sum_{i=1}^{5}(i^2-8i+7)$$ $$=360-55+8.5.3-7.5=390$$
We have used $\sum_{k=1}^{n}=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1), \sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$

Comment: Thanks, but why the upper bound became ( i-1) ?

Comment: The sum from $j=i$ to $j=12$ equals sum from 1 to 12 -sum from  $j=1$ to $j=i-1$ . it should not be $i$, then the sum will be $j=i+1$ to $12$.

Comment: @Tarek Chafel For example sum (5,12)=sum(1,12)-sum(1,4).